# Can't save file after opening in network mapped directory via .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have am using the following code to open up several files in an existing network mapped directory

```
pushd \\networkdirectory\subfolder
start file1.xlsx
start file2.xls
```

The problem is that because I'm using `pushd` it maps a temporary UNC directory and then when I try to save the .xlsx file in Excel after making changes, it says

```
'Z:\\networkdirectory\subfolder' cannot be found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not map the location to something more permanent, take a look a `Net Use`.

Comment: `pushd` creates a twmporary drive for UNC paths and changes to it as the current working directory; perhaps try `start "" /D . file1.xlsx`?

Comment: The file is being stored on the network instead of locally and I don't have access to change the network. All I want to do is open up the file using a .bat file and be able to save it back on the network. I don't need a temporary drive, I want to use the existing network drive.

Comment: Use the existing network drive then. `pushd "<ExistingNetworkDrive>:\subfolder"` or `cd /d "<ExistingNetworkDrive>:\subfolder"` or `start "" "<ExistingNetworkDrive>:\subfolder\file1.xlsx"`

Comment: Thank you Mofi, that solved it! I wish I could give you points for this. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command **PUSHD** with by default enabled command extensions creates a temporary drive letter that points to the network resource specified with UNC path starting with drive letter `Z:` on not being already used. This behavior is explained by help of command **PUSHD** output by running in a command prompt window `pushd /?`. Then the directory with the temporary drive letter becomes the current directory.

This often wanted behavior is contra-productive in this case because of the two Excel files without path are loaded using current directory path by Microsoft Excel started two times as a parallel running process. So Windows command processor immediately continues with batch file processing after starting Excel twice with the two files in current directory. The initial current directory before execution of **PUSHD** is restored with removing the temporary drive letter `Z:` although Excel is still running with the two files opened. That results in the error message on later saving the Excel files.

The solution is omitting the command **PUSHD** as Excel has absolutely no problem to open a file specified on command line with a UNC path.

```
start "" "\\networkdirectory\subfolder\file1.xlsx"
start "" "\\networkdirectory\subfolder\file2.xls"
```

The first double quoted argument string is interpreted by command **START** as optional title for command process window. So it is necessary to specify explicitly a title string. In this case an empty title string is specified with `""` because of Excel is a Windows GUI application and so no Windows command process with an additional console window is opened at all. Run in a command prompt window `start /?` for help on command **START**.